# Internet explorer delets the manifest.appcache file when offline

Tags: internet-explorer, browser-cache, offline-caching

IE Offline caching using 'Appication Cache' and manifest file is breaking.

**Issue:**

1) When I load my page from the server using IE10 browser, the manifest file is created and the required files are stored to the caching folder

2) To test the offline mode, I undeploy the application from server and then try to load the page from the IE browser. T

- the page is loaded from the cache for the first time
- behind the scene IE trying to fetch a copy of the 'manifest.appcache' from the server. But this results in a 404 as the application is undeployed from the server. And then IE browser automatically removes the cached 'manifest.appcache' file from the local cache.

  - the next time I try to load my appication page, I get a 404..as there is no manifest file is available locally to recreate the page.

**Questions:**

1) Is it a bug with IE or is it supposed to work as described below.

2) What change should I do to ensure that my page is cached to work offline.

Answer (score 0):

As per the http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/

Its a browser feature to delete the manifest file from the local cache if the server returns either a '404' or '410' for the manifest file.

If the request for manifest file could reach the server, but couldn't find the manifest file in the server then it will return a 404....thats why me page wasn't working

In the case of real scenario of unable to reach the server (offline) then the request for the manifest file would have just aborted by the browser as there is no response from the server. In this case the manifest file wouldn't be deleted by the browser and the user can continue working offline.